# How to create a latitude/longitude 2D array from a csv file in Python 3?

Tags: python, csv, multidimensional-array, latitude-longitude

I have a .csv file, containing a lot of data in this format:

```
Latitude    Longitude   agric
-------------------------------
   49.35    -7.05   0
   49.35    -7.04   0
   49.35    -7.02   0
   49.35    -7.01   0
   49.35    -6.99   0
   49.35    -6.98   0
   49.35    -6.97   0
   49.35    -6.95   0
   49.35    -6.94   0
   49.35    -6.92   0
   49.35    -6.91   0
   49.35    -6.9    0
   49.35    -6.88   0
   49.35    -6.87   0
   49.35    -6.85   0
   49.35    -6.84   0
   49.35    -6.83   0
   49.35    -6.81   0
   49.35    -6.8    0
```

I need to create a 2D array from this csv file, so that column 3 (Agricultural emissions) are spatially represented by their long/lat in a 2D array.

I'm very very new to Python so any help will be massively appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Here you go: [python docs](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python). When you will have some problems with your implementation, post your code and ask about specific issue.

Comment: To be even more specific: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: pip install numpy  #numpy.loadcsv('csv_file_name')

Answer (score 0):

try with pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(<<filename with path>>)
```

you will get a dataframe out of the file, and then you can manipulate it as you please into an array

Comment: np.loadcsv ? That will just immediately get him an array

Comment: this sounds even better